# Why do GMs look up during calculations?

Tags: grandmaster, calculation, board-vision, visualization

I saw some grandmasters looking up or sideways during calculations. Why don't they just look at the board and visualize? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: They may get confused by where the pieces actually are (which messes up with where they are calculating them to be in the future)

Comment: I took a few lessons from a then IM, now GM. He strongly recommended NOT looking at the board for the reason given by @David

Comment: In Chapter 1 ("The Chess Image") of his book *Psychology in Chess*, Nikolai Krogius gives several examples of famous grandmasters miscalculating because they mentally left a piece or pawn on its original square during their mental calculations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on the great comments of @David and @Timothy Chow, GM Nikolai Krogius talks about the role of the **residual image** in his book *Psychology in Chess*. This is an image that stays  and blurs the calculations. The residual image is the transfer of judgment from a past position to a new situation. The past then acts on the present.

To combat this residual image and to improve concentration, Krogius recommends practicing **blindfold chess or analyzing without using a chess board**. By not looking at the board, the player must constantly check the position of the pieces, thus erasing the residual image.

---

Here is an example of the residual image. At the beginning of the position the Bishop in b3 controls the square g8, but not ... at the end.

```
[FEN "r3k3/1p5p/p2R4/4p1Q1/4P1bP/PBq5/6P1/5K2 w - - 0 1"]
[title "Ilyin-Genevsky - Nenarokov, Moscow 1922"]

1.Bf7+! Kf8 2.Qh6+?? (2.Rf6!+-) Kxf7 3.Rf6+? (3.Qxh7+ Ke8 4.Qg6+ Ke7 5.Qf6+=) Kg8! {and now Black is better!}
```

---

Check also this article on [ChessBase India](https://chessbase.in/news/Vidit-Gujrathi-solving-studies), which asks your question

> ***We often see top chess players not looking at the board while
>   calculating**. It seems that their attention is somewhere else, yet
>   after a few minutes they make the move without having even glanced at
>   the position. What do you think they were doing for the last few
>   minutes? Well, they were thinking in their head. They did not need to
>   see the chess board to calculate the variations. They could do it in
>   their head. So how do these super GMs calculate without a chess board?
>   How are they able to make complex decisions in their mind, which
>   normal players cannot fathom.

They welcome GM Vidit Gujrathi on how to calculate better in blindfold.